# My Wordpress Site Shows Like This

Tags: wordpress

I use a google cloud server and all my plugins are up to date I just woke up and saw my wordpress site not loading proper just showing links up no styles any suggestion please on fix see site here 
https://taffy.com.ng

Comment: Restore your backup.

Answer (score 0):

It may be cache issue. Try to clear your browser cache. 
Given link working fine on my side.